# How to get last children class jquery

Tags: jquery

I try to distinguish last children in div. I have something like below. I want to check which is last, `children1` or `children2`.

This script doing just if, no matter what class is at the end.

```js
if ($('.parent').children('.children1').last()) {
  alert("children1");
  // do something
} else if ($('.parent').children('.children2').last()) {
  alert("children2");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children1"></div>
  <div class="children2"></div>
  <div class="children1"></div>
  <div class="children2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can use `:last` to get the last child element, then `is()` or `hasClass()` to determine which class it has:

```js
var $lastChild = $('.parent div:last');
if ($lastChild.is('.children1')) {
  alert("children1");
  // do something
} else if ($lastChild.is('.children2')) {
  alert("children2");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children1"></div>
  <div class="children2"></div>
  <div class="children1"></div>
  <div class="children2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can I use ID? I have multiple classes in my div

Comment: You probably could, but without seeing how your actual HTML looks it's a guess. So long as you don't repeat the `id` then you should be fine. Using classes is a better idea generally, though, as you can have the same JS logic work for all instances of the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Although ugly IMHO you can use the [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method. The following function accepts two parameters:

1. **parentSelector:** CSS selector string of the parent element.
2. **targetSelector:** CSS selector string of the elements that need to be targeted.

```js
const last = (parentSelector, targetSelector) => {
  return $(parentSelector).children(targetSelector).last().attr('class');
}

console.log(last('.parent', '.c1, .c2'));
```

```html
<section class="parent">
  <div class="c1"></div>
  <aside class="c2"></aside>
  <figure class="c1"></figure>
  <section class="c2"></section>
  <div class="c1"></div>
  <div class="c3"></div>
  <div class="c2"></div>
  <ol class='c3'>
    <li class='c1'></li>
    <li class='c2'></li>
  </ol>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what if i have inside child more divs?

Comment: It will always find the last direct child of  `.parent` and return that child's `.className`. See [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59455469/2813224).

Comment: how to write condition with this? if attr class=something {} ?

Comment: Updated into a function.